# Help to understand this 5V relay module's diode

Tags: diodes, relay, protection

[image]

Hello people, I need a bit of clarification regarding the below module, especially with the diode that is used. Does anybody know the value of it? If it is 1n4148, is it a Zener diode? What will be the biasing of it, whether it is wired to be forward biased for the relay coil or reverse biased and set to work in the breakdown region?

Comment: Please post a schematic of it. Without it, it's guesswork. Best guesswork: flyback diode for the relay coil.

Comment: @winny, to even draw the schematic correctly, I need to know its value. I would like to know looking at the picture, is it a zener diode operating in forward bias?

Comment: You can (sometimes) recognize MELF diodes types by the color band. Black = General Purpose, Blue = Zener, Green = Schottky.

Comment: You don't need to know the value or type of the diode to draw a schematic.  Sketch with a standard diode symbol.  You can then tell from the diagram what the diode is doing and what type would make sense.

Comment: Schematic ? Just see this https://components101.com/switches/5v-single-channel-relay-module-pinout-features-applications-working-datasheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diode is most likely an [LL4148](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ll4148-d.pdf), one of the most common and inexpensive diodes on the [planet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109011130_YONGYUTAI-LL4148_C2891733.pdf). From [here](https://components101.com/switches/5v-single-channel-relay-module-pinout-features-applications-working-datasheet) as noted by @Antonio51, we can find a representative schematic:

[image]

Chances are good the transistor will be an [S8050](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109011130_YONGYUTAI-S8050_C2891804.pdf) (marked J3Y).

The diode provides a path for the energy stored in the relay coil inductance when the transistor switches 'off', thus protecting the transistor. Otherwise the transistor would be subjected to undesirable conditions (breakdown at close to the relay coil current). It is reverse-biased or has 0V across it except for a brief time (milliseconds in duration) just after the transistor switches off.

Answer (score 3):

It is a flyback diode to protect the transistor from reverse voltage pulse when the relay switches off. It likely is a 1N4148 which is a standard silicon switching signal diode used on hobbyist electronic modules

Comment: thank you @JRE for the correction